# What is the purpose of "#*" hash and star symbols before the parameters passed to a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have the following query which gets called from ASP.NET application and creates a subset of rows within the same table "DETAILS" and the subset is defined by parameters $f2 and $f3 used for paging purposes.

```
INSERT INTO DETAILS (ID, UIN, ACTIVE_IND, UGUID, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE)
SELECT AF.ID, AF.UIN, AF.ACTIVE, AF.UGUID, AF.CREATED_BY, AF.CREATED_DATE FROM 
(SELECT #*$f0 ID, DET.UIN, DET.ACTIVE_IND, DET.UGUID, DET.CREATED_BY, DET.CREATED_DATE, 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY P.PRODUCT_ID) FG 
        FROM DETAILS DET 
        JOIN PRODUCTS P ON P.UIN = DET.UIN 
        WHERE ID = #*$f1 ) AF 
    WHERE AF.FG BETWEEN #*$f2 AND #*$f3
```

The ASP.NET c# code that calls this query looks like this

```
 new SqlDataSource().ExecuteSql("InsertDetails",
                new List<object>() {_subSetId, _mainSetId, start, end});
```

"InsertDetails" is the name of the above query and "start" "end" are the paging range.

**My question is:** What function or purpose have the "#*" before the parameters in this query??. I need to replicate this query for other tables but would like to know why are the parameters passed like this "#*$f0", "#*$f1", "#*$f2" and "#*$f3".

Comment: These are not legal forms for column or variable names in T-SQL (unless escaped by brackets, of course), nor does `SqlDataSource` do anything special with this (that I can find). How are you getting this query text?

Comment: Sometimes such weird characters are used as place holders which are replaced on string level before the call (kind of dynamic command generation)... Neither beautifull nor clean, but sometimes - well - you know... You might use the profiler to monitor the statement which is processed acutally

Comment: The standard `SqlDataSource` class does not have any `ExecuteSql` method that I can see. Are you using a custom `SqlDataSource` class, a custom `ExecuteSql` extension method, or did I just completely overlook something?

Comment: @Shnugo, Thanks for the comment, if you where to put this as your answer I will accept it because that's exactly what it was, those 2 characters "#*" are used as place holders to be replace in another method to customise the query to SQL server and to Oracle syntax, is painfull but was the only way can be implemented

Comment: @hvd, Yes Executesql is an extension method

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert, You are right, thet is not legal T-SQL syntax, is just random characters used as place holders as Shnugo pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked me to put my comment as answer. It seems that I had the correct guess:

> Sometimes such weird characters are used as place holders which are
>   replaced on string level before the call (kind of dynamic command
>   generation)... Neither beautifull nor clean, but sometimes - well -
>   you know...
>
> You might use the profiler to monitor the statement which
>   is processed acutally

Happy Coding!